# Смена содержимого div'а каждую среду

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы содержимое внутри блока `<div>` менялось каждую среду.
Думал можно решить через таймер, но у меня не вышло. Вот что у меня получилось:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="route route1">Роут 1</div>
<div class="route route2">Роут 2</div>
<div class="route route3">Роут 3</div>
<div class="route route4">Роут 4</div>
<div class="route route5">Роут 5</div>

var routeIndex = 1;
function RouteRotator() {
  $(".route").hide();
  $(".route" + routeIndex).show();
  
  var routeCount = 5;
  routeIndex++;
  if(routeIndex > routeCount) {
    routeIndex = 1;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  RouteRotator();
  setInterval(RouteRotator, 3000);
});
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Comment: любой слайдер возьмите - это и будет ротатор новостей

Comment: Слайдер не совсем подходит, в конечном итоге это должно будет стать просто кнопкой которая каждую среду ведет на новую страницу. Таких страниц будет 12.